# How to fix linker error unresolved external std::locale::id::id in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

When compiling a C++ Builder 10.4 project, I get the following linker error:

> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::locale::id::id(unsigned int)' referenced from C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\21.0\DCP\SCREEN2VIDEO.LIB|Screen2Video

This linker error happens when 'Link with dynamic RTL', and 'Link with run-time packages' are turned off. When linking with dynamic RTL, the linker error does not occur, but I want to link statically.

The SCREEN2VIDEO.LIB is from a package containing an imported ActiveX control.

Comment: What do you need? Dynamic or static linked runtime env? It depends how the ActiveX or DLL is built and linked?!

Comment: To link a project statically, make sure you also disable Runtime Packages, too.  Disabling the Dynamic RTL is not enough

Answer (score 1):

Recompile all dependent packages (including the screen2video.bpl) with dynamic RTL turned off. This fixed the linker error.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, with C++ Builder 11 though. It turned out to be a problem of the optimizer. Try disabling all optimizations.
Also check out one of the related bug reports at Embarcadero:
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-29221

Edit: I experimented a bit more and found the problematic compiler flag. It is **-finline-functions** which is implicitely added when using -O2 or higher.
Therefore, as a workaround, you can add **-fno-inline-functions** to C++ compiler > Advanced > Additional Options to make it work without too much of a performance impact at least.

I also added this info to the above bug-report.